# how to call for json with conditions in ios 9, using objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

This is my json web response response.

```
-Itinerary: [
    -{
        ID: "1",
        ValueOne: "2473.05",
        ValueTwo: "368.95"

    },
    -{
        ID: "2",
        ValueOne: "2453.05",
        ValueTwo: "308.95"

    }
],
-Details :[
    -{
        ID:"1",
        FirstName:"Graham",
        LastName:"Json"
    },
    -{
        ID:"1",
        FirstName:"Anuradh",
        LastName:"Stackoverflow"
    }

]
```

What should be the `response` object type.I do like this, is it correct or it does not matter whatever the type

```
NSDictionary *Results = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
```

then I get the response.now what I want is to get `itinerary` details and
get the `Details` only where the `itinerary ID` is equal to `Details ID` .how can I do that.

```
   NSArray *Itinerary = [Resulsts objectForKey=@"Itinerary"];
    NSArray *Itinerary = [Resulsts objectForKey=@"Detailss"];

    for(NSDictionary *itinry in Itinerary)
    {
        NSString *Iid = [itinry objectForKey="ID"];
        NSString *ValOne = [itinry objectForKey="ValueOne"];
        //like this I'm getting values
        //then here I want to get all details which it's `itinerary` `ID` equal to `Details` `ID`.how can I do that.
    }
```

then here I want to get all details which it's `itinerary` `ID` equal to `Details` `ID`.how can I do that.

Comment: You have two option 1. remove '-' from JSON string & then fetch ID & Details.  2. use  NSArray *Itinerary = [Resulsts objectForKey=@"-Itinerary"]; for getting values & later remove '-' from  all values.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this code Hope it will work for you

```
  NSArray *Itinerary = [Resulsts objectForKey=@"Itinerary"];
    NSArray *dTinerary = [Resulsts objectForKey=@"Detailss"];

    for(int i=0; i<Itinerary;i++)
    {
        NSString *iID=[[Itinerary objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"ID"];

        NSString *dID=[[dTinerary objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"ID"];

        if ([iID isEqualToString:dID])
        {

            // do your thinks here

            NSLog(@"%@",[[Itinerary objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"ValueOne"]);
               // break;
        }

//        NSString *Iid = [itinry objectForKey="ID"];
       // NSString *ValOne = [itinry objectForKey="ValueOne"];
        //like this I'm getting values
        //then here I want to get all details which it's `itinerary` `ID` equal to `Details` `ID`.how can I do that.
    }
```

Comment: how to get Details if two IDs are equal

Comment: NSString *getDetails =[[Itinerary objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"ValueOne"];

Comment: think when `Itinerary` `ID`=`1` and `Details` `ID`=`1` at that point I want to get the all details in the `Details` array where its `ID`=`1`.

Comment: NSString *getID =[[dTinerary objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"ID"] ; NSString *get FirstName =[[dTinerary objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"FirstName"];NSString *get LastName =[[dTinerary objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"LastName"];

Comment: I voted up, if it works well for me then I will accept.thanx and good one